# Angular Universal Window.addEventListener is not a function issue

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am getting the following issue while running npm run dev:ssr in my local.

```
D:\Projects\AngularUniversal\ssrfile\dist\ssr-project\server\main.js:192481
            window.addEventListener('test', null, Object.defineProperty({}, 'passive', {
                   ^

TypeError: window.addEventListener is not a function
    at supportsPassiveEventListeners (D:\Projects\AngularUniversal\ssrfile\dist\ssr-project\server\main.js:192481:20)    at normalizePassiveListenerOptions (D:\Projects\AngularUniversal\ssrfile\dist\ssr-project\server\main.js:192498:12)
    at Module.mPVK (D:\Projects\AngularUniversal\ssrfile\dist\ssr-project\server\main.js:304346:121)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Projects\AngularUniversal\ssrfile\dist\ssr-project\server\main.js:26:30)
    at Module.PCNd (D:\Projects\AngularUniversal\ssrfile\dist\ssr-project\server\main.js:185750:83)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Projects\AngularUniversal\ssrfile\dist\ssr-project\server\main.js:26:30)
    at Module.ct+p (D:\Projects\AngularUniversal\ssrfile\dist\ssr-project\server\main.js:255785:79)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Projects\AngularUniversal\ssrfile\dist\ssr-project\server\main.js:26:30)
    at Module.ZAI4 (D:\Projects\AngularUniversal\ssrfile\dist\ssr-project\server\main.js:235791:75)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Projects\AngularUniversal\ssrfile\dist\ssr-project\server\main.js:26:30)

A server error has occurred.
node exited with 1 code.
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:65206
```

I've used the below dependencies for my project.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.2.6",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^11.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "^11.2.3",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^11.0.1",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^11.2.1",
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "@types/pdfjs-dist": "^2.7.4",
    "angular-fusioncharts": "3.0.4",
    "braintree-web-drop-in": "^1.27.0",
    "clipboard": "^2.0.8",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "croppie": "^2.6.5",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^5.7.0",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "fusioncharts": "3.15.1-sr.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.7",
    "html2pdf.js": "^0.9.2",
    "jspdf": "^2.3.1",
    "mydatepicker": "^9.0.2",
    "ng-lazyload-image": "^9.1.0",
    "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.8.3",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.4.1",
    "ngx-gallery-9": "^1.0.6",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-scroll-event": "^2.0.2",
    "ngx-webcam": "0.2.0",
    "node": "^12.14.0",
    "node-sass": "4.11.0",
    "nouislider": "^14.6.4",
    "recordrtc": "5.4.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.6",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1002.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.2.3",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^11.2.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.32",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.22",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.3.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.5",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0"
  }
}
```

what is wrong in it?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run code with `node` which is intended to run in a browser. Are you trying to start a development server for an Angular application?

Comment: @majusebetter Yes, I am adding angular universal SSR in my existing application.

Comment: Which NodeJS version are you using? Could you post the output of `node -v`?

Comment: Node version is 10.23.0.

Comment: You need version `^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0`, according to https://angular.io/guide/universal. See `engines` property in this `package.json`: https://unpkg.com/browse/@angular/platform-server@12.1.2/package.json

Comment: Ok will update the nodejs and let you know. Thanks @manjusbetter

Comment: This issue is fixed if I remove recordrtc from our project. It didn't support SSR.